# Centering an element in its parent element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a slideshow, and I'm trying to vertically center its nav buttons above the images. I'm trying top:50%, but it moves relative to the button's height, not the height of the slideshow. I'm using jQuery Cycle.

```
<div class="slideshow_container">
<h2>Amor Insecta</h2>
<div class="slideshow_controls">
<div class="cycle_prev">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="cycle_next">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow">
<img title="stylepageart2.jpg" src="http://cmpltunknwn.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/stylepageart21.jpg" alt="stylepageart2.jpg" /> 
<img title="stylepageart3.jpg" src="http://cmpltunknwn.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/stylepageart22.jpg" alt="stylepageart3.jpg" /> 
</div>
</div>

.slideshow_container {
width:90%;
margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
max-height:2000px;
}

.slideshow {
position: relative;
width: 100% !important;
}

.slideshow img {
width: 100% !important;
height:auto !important;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.slideshow_controls {
display:none;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
z-index:100!important;
}

.cycle_prev, .cycle_next {  
position:absolute;
top:50%;
width:37px;
height:37px;
}

.cycle_prev{
left:0;
background:url(http://cmpltunknwn.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/theme_images/prev.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.cycle_next {
right:0;
background:url(http://cmpltunknwn.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/theme_images/next.jpg) no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: The problem is that your elements are positioned as absolute elements. Thus they don't get a useable height. My suggestion: calculate the height of your desire and set it with JavaScript. Then it will be much easier.

Comment: @KittMedia: Could you give me any leads about how to do it, please?

Comment: The easiest way would be in this case `$('img').height();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the ideal solution, but for your code it works. Remove the `top: 50%` from the prev/next buttons and add a padding-top to their container:  http://jsfiddle.net/4qSPr/

Note: I removed the display: none; of the arrows for the example...

CSS

```
.slideshow_controls {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
z-index:100!important;
padding-top: 30%;
}

.cycle_prev, .cycle_next {  
position:absolute;
width:37px;
height:37px;
}
```

Comment: Hm, the fiddle works, but on my site, where the nav buttons show only on hover, when you hover over the image, the image is pushed down.'http://cmpltunknwn.mybigcommerce.com/style/'

Comment: I added float:left to .slideshow-controls, and now the image is not pushed down. Thanks.